# Como pegar o link de uma página e atribuí-lo a uma variável em PHP?

Tags: php

Estou querendo utilizar os plugins do Facebook sobre comentário, só que não quero ter que ficar trocando o código em cada página só por causa do link. Tem como fazer uma função que pega o link automaticamente e atribui a uma variável pra colocar essa variavel no `data-href` no código abaixo?

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Comment: Miguel, você poderia [edit] sua pergunta adicionando um exemplo de como está o seu código? Isso facilita na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Em resumo...

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?= "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ?>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

dessa forma você vai estar colocando no data-href o endereço da página atual, porém cuidado, essa prática não é muito segura pois o HTTP_HOST pode ser alterado.

Comment: Como assim pode ser alterado?

Comment: @MiguelGoffredo, sim, eu posso alterar o HTTP_HOST na minha maquina enquanto acesso o seu site. Claro que o máximo que vou conseguir é afetar a minha navegação e caso eu comente no post, vou comentar com o caminho que eu quiser... mas apenas funciona para a pessoa que está fazendo a alteração. No seu exemplo, pode usar sem problema, mas não use essas variáveis para coisas que precise de mais segurança.

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o porque dessas variáveis do HTTP_HOST e a REQUEST_URI não são seguras. Me desculpe se estiver sendo muito "burro" mas essas variáveis podem ser outras quaisquer? Eu estava tentando achar uma função para pegar o link e adicionar à uma variável, mas desse jeito que você fez deu certo também. E com os social plugins do FB tem como fazer moderação para aceitar ou não o comentário, não sei se isso dá uma certa segurança, se puder me ajudar fico agradecido. @RafaelRibeiro

Comment: @MiguelGoffredo pode ficar tranquilo, no seu caso não tem "insegurança" apenas alertei que dependendo de para que se use essas variáveis pode causar problemas na aplicação, mas isso só em uso mais específico em servidores.

Answer (score -1):

Acho que isso vai deixar faltando uma barra, o certo não seria:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?= "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]"."/"."$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]" ?>" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

Comment: Não... o $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] já vem com /